# Como mudar a cor dos itens de uma lista no Python?

Tags: python, lista

Estou começando a aprender Python e possuo pouco conhecimento nessa área.
Com o intuito de aprimorar meu conhecimento, elaborei um algoritmo para um jogo de dados que possuo. Ele funciona perfeitamente. No entanto, gostaria de implementar algumas cores nos textos para ficar mais prático.

Segue o código abaixo.

```
# Simulação de batalha Massive Darkness

import random 

#dados
yellow_dice=[0,1,1,1,1,2]
red_dice=[0,1,1,2,2,3]
blue_dice=[0,0,1,1,1,2]
green_dice=[0,0,1,2,2,3]

#dados de ataque
dados_ataque_1=int(input('Quantos dados de ataque amarelo serão jogados? '))
print ()
dados_ataque_2=int(input('Quantos dados de ataque vermelho serão jogados? '))
ataque_yellow=[]
ataque_red=[]
bonus_ataque=[]
print ()

#dados de defesa
dados_defesa_1=int(input('Quantos dados de defesa azul serão jogados? '))
print ()
dados_defesa_2=int(input('Quantos dados de ataque verde serão jogados? '))
def_blue=[]
def_green=[]
bonus_def=[]


if (dados_ataque_1==1):
  yellow_1=(random.choice(yellow_dice))
  ataque_yellow.append(yellow_1)
elif (dados_ataque_1==2):
  yellow_1=(random.choice(yellow_dice))
  yellow_2=(random.choice(yellow_dice))
  ataque_yellow.append(yellow_1)
  ataque_yellow.append(yellow_2)
elif (dados_ataque_1==3):
  yellow_1=(random.choice(yellow_dice))
  yellow_2=(random.choice(yellow_dice))
  yellow_3=(random.choice(yellow_dice))
  ataque_yellow.append(yellow_1)
  ataque_yellow.append(yellow_2)
  ataque_yellow.append(yellow_3)
if (dados_ataque_2==1):
  red_1=(random.choice(red_dice))
  ataque_red.append(red_1)
elif (dados_ataque_2==2):
  red_1=(random.choice(red_dice))
  red_2=(random.choice(red_dice))
  ataque_red.append(red_1)
  ataque_red.append(red_2)
elif (dados_ataque_2==3):
  red_1=(random.choice(red_dice))
  red_2=(random.choice(red_dice))
  red_3=(random.choice(red_dice))
  ataque_red.append(red_1)
  ataque_red.append(red_2)
  ataque_red.append(red_3)

ataque_total=(sum(ataque_yellow) + sum(ataque_red))

for a in (ataque_yellow):
  if (a==2):
    bonus_ataque.append('☼')

for b in (ataque_red):
  if (b==2):
    bonus_ataque.append('☼')

for c in (ataque_red):
  if (c==3):
    bonus_ataque.append('♦')

print()
print()
print ('Os dados de ataque amarelo foram:', ataque_yellow)
print ('Os dados de ataque vermelho foram:', ataque_red)
print ('Os bônus de ataque são:' ,bonus_ataque)
print ('O ataque total é:', ataque_total)

if (dados_defesa_1==1):
  blue_1=(random.choice(blue_dice))
  def_blue.append(blue_1)
elif (dados_defesa_1==2):
  blue_1=(random.choice(blue_dice))
  blue_2=(random.choice(blue_dice))
  def_blue.append(blue_1)
  def_blue.append(blue_2)
elif (dados_defesa_1==3):
  blue_1=(random.choice(blue_dice))
  blue_2=(random.choice(blue_dice))
  blue_3=(random.choice(blue_dice))
  def_blue.append(blue_1)
  def_blue.append(blue_2)
  def_blue.append(blue_3)
if (dados_defesa_2==1):
  green_1=(random.choice(green_dice))
  def_green.append(green_1)
elif (dados_defesa_2==2):
  green_1=(random.choice(green_dice))
  green_2=(random.choice(green_dice))
  def_green.append(green_1)
  def_green.append(green_2)
elif (dados_defesa_2==3):
  green_1=(random.choice(green_dice))
  green_2=(random.choice(green_dice))
  green_3=(random.choice(green_dice))
  def_green.append(green_1)
  def_green.append(green_2)
  def_green.append(green_3)

def_total=(sum(def_blue) + sum(def_green))

for d in (def_blue):
  if (d==2):
    bonus_def.append('☼')

for e in (def_green):
  if (e==2):
    bonus_def.append('☼')

for f in (def_green):
  if (f==3):
    bonus_def.append('♦')

print()
print()

print ('Os dados de defesa azul foram:', def_blue)
print ('Os dados de defesa verde foram:', def_green)
print ('Os bônus de defesa são:' ,bonus_def)
print ('A defesa total é:', def_total)

print()
print()

resultado=(ataque_total-def_total)

if (ataque_total>def_total):
  print ('O atacante causou', resultado, 'de dano')
else:
  print('O defensor não sofreu dano')
```

Gostaria que os valores dos vetores/listas ficassem com suas respectivas cores.

```
ataque_yellow=[]
ataque_red=[]
def_blue=[]
def_green=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colorir os prints com as cores que você quer, os códigos de cores são estes:

```
Azul = '\033[94m'
Verde = '\033[92m'
Amarelo = '\033[93m'
Vermelho = '\033[91m'
Fim = '\033[0m'
```

Nos prints:

```
print ('Os dados de ataque amarelo foram: \033[93m' + ataque_yellow + '\033[0m')
```

Para ficar mais fácil, você pode utilizar [essa classe que encontrei no Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944/14100521), que foi de onde tirei esta resposta.